# Svn to Git along history

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

i am trying to migrate the old projects from SVN to git,There is a small problem.The old SVN repositories consists of Branches,Tags,Trunks.When it comes to git it is in the different structure. How may i supposed to do this.Or if i manually commit the old SVN code to git the history will come along with this or not.Please can some one help on this.

Comment: Is this about a one-time migration and you only want to use Git afterwards, or do you only want to use the Git clone as frontend and commit back to SVN from the Git clone?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do two things.

- Get svn dump and move to new server
- Migration svn to git

For first thing, use these command from [this link](https://www.petefreitag.com/item/665.cfm).

```
# in old server
svnadmin dump /path/to/repository > repo_name.svn_dump
# move dump to new server using tool like `scp`
# in new server
svnadmin create /path/to/repository
svnadmin load /path/to/repository < repo_name.svn_dump
```

For second thing, use this command.

```
git svn init SVN_URL -T Trunk -b Branches -t Tags --prefix=svn/
```

Comment: Really i am new to this type of migrations. My intention is, first of all i will get all the source code from the svn to my local drive. Then i want  to push it to the empty git which was created earlier in the gitlab. So my doubt is when i push like this, Is the history will come or  i have to do any thing. Thanks for your response.

Comment: As I know SVN log will be converted to GIT commit appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

For a one-time migration `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for conversions of repositories or repository parts. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want and it is a gazillion faster.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)